# Create an already populated dashboard with a displayed graph in Atoti using Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, atoti

I'm not sure how to word this differently but I'm integrating Atoti with a Django project using their project template, I've searched a lot in their documentation but I can't seem to get an answer about this.

What I need to do is after a button click on a Django view, redirect the user to a custom Atoti Dashboard that's already populated with a specific information already displayed (for example, a line graph with a title). I don't need to save it unless the user wants because we're planning on using Atoti mainly as means of visualization.

At this point in time, I can only redirect the user to the standard Atoti dashboard with my information and then create what I need to display but that's not user friendly at all and presumes the user has knowledge with Atoti.

Anyone know if this is possible and if isn't, anyone has any suggestions on good Data Visualization libraries that make use of Django?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the custom atoti dashboard and use its ID (the last part of the URL when you have the dashboard opened in a browser tab) to redirect your user to `f"{session_url}/#/dashboard/{dashboard_id}"`.